# Rails 3.1 Assets pipeline and JS preprocessing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I want to put some user preferences in my JavaScript. Previously I've done it by rendering my JavaSript file *preferences.js.erb* by controller via <%= javascript_link_tag ...>. How it should be cooked now with 3.1 Assets pipeline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In no way.. application.js is static - on production it is generated into one big static file by `rake assets:precompile` command.

So you can include separate file *preferences.js.erb* as you proposed or render preferences directly on page - second is better because you save 1 request (but worse because they won`t be cached).
To minimize size of preferences it would be better to present them in JSON, like this:

```
def user_preferences
  javascript_tag "
    var user_settings = #{ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(current_user.settings)}
  "
end
```